# How to use biblatex's \addperiod outside the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

Sometimes the `\addperiod` command from `biblatex` could be useful in other situations as well. How to use it outside the bibliography?

M(N)WE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

text \addperiod

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command is internally defined as `\blx@imc@addperiod`. To make it available:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addperiod}{\blx@imc@addperiod}  
\makeatother

\begin{document}

text \addperiod

\end{document}
```

Comment: But note that `\adderiod` relies in part on the category code regime set up in `biblatex`. Some things will work, but not all. Compare and contrast the output of `\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addperiod}{\blx@imc@addperiod}  
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro{cite}{text, \the\spacefactor\quad text,\addperiod}
\frenchspacing

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson}

[text, \the\spacefactor\quad text,\addperiod]
\end{document}`

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the warning! Seems I was lucky that I only needed it to add some forgotten periods.